# Setup PHP Mail Function using Custom php.ini

Tags: php, email, local

I want to create an auto-mailer in my website for the "Forgot Password" function. Unfortunately, I don't have an access or even privilege to edit the php.ini file.
I contacted my web hosting technical support and they just told me that they cannot modify the php.ini for my auto-mail. They just told me to create my own local php.ini file (maybe residing in my own www directory) and set the session path locally.
The question is, how can I do that? How can I configure the PHP's mail() function using a local php.ini?

Comment: you shouldn't need to edit php.ini to just send email on a shared host

Comment: @Dagon How can I do that?

Comment: You don't need to edit php.ini to send mail. PHP's `mail()` function is essentially USELESS for anything "advanced". Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both very good free packages, instead.

Comment: `mail(FILL IN THE BLANKS)`

Comment: I just used Swiftmailer and its now working :-)
Thanks for info @MarcB :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
```

To set the custom php ini values you need for that specific script.

This is documented at https://www.php.net/ini_set